# Eclipse Plugin-Project bundle cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bundle, resolve

I checked out an Eclipse Plugin-Project from [GitHub](https://github.com/bkahlert/com.bkahlert.nebula) and wanted to start it (and edit, but that is not the focus). But in the MANIFEST.MF it says

```
Bundle 'org.apache.log4j' cannot be resolved
```

and some other missing bundle messages. I know that I have to download the bundle version of log4j, which I have done from [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.apache.log4j&version=1.2.15). After that, I created a new folder and added a new target directory linking to this folder. But I still got the message that the bundle is missing in the manifest file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also found this post but it didn't work.

Comment: Were you able to create a Target definition with log4j within?

Comment: Yes. I opened the Properties -> Plugin... -> Target Platform and there I could see 'Running Platform (Active)'. O clicked on it, clicked on 'Edit' button and added a directory, where the log4j bundle was downloaded. Then a clicked on the button 'apply' but nothing changed.

Comment: Probably what you've downloaded was not a bundle (bundle can be in a jar, but not every jar is a bundle). Try adding http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/ update site in TP and select log4j from it.

Comment: Wow, great! This did it! The files from the spring source site where not bundles! Thx :)